# Is it possible to configure MongoDB programmatically?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to automate replica set configuration and deployment (perhaps ask the user for a few inputs) in MongoDB, but without feeding a JavaScript file into the MongoDB shell (as scripts don't take parameters), or reading the standard output from the shell in an application (as that feels like a bit of a hack). Is this possible? Do any of the drivers support this? I've been digging for a while and can't seem to find anything, but I thought I'd ask here (Oh, Wise Ones!).

Comment: Everything is possible when you believe  (Yes)

Comment: You might have not heard of [MMS](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/) for MongoDB. So before you reinvent the wheel, it might be worth a look. There are deployment options available along with various other things.

Comment: Hey @BlakesSeven. I have, but unfortunately it's not an option for the project I'm working on. I would love nothing more than to use MMS, but no dice.

Comment: Your question is, well quite "broad". You need to think of the things you really want to do. You also might try "digging into the source" of [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools), which does a number of things such as spin up "test configurations" of Replica sets and sharded clusters. So the lessons learned from there could be a valuable guide. But asking *"Hey wise ones, how do I do this **huge** task?"*, This is StackOverflow answers, and not a blog series. Pointers are the best we can do without a "specific" task ask.

Comment: I don't see my question as being broad. It is quite succinct, in fact. All I want to know is if something is possible. You don't need to provide me with source code, just perhaps somewhere to look that I may not have thought of. If I had said, 'Is it possible to interface with MongoDB in Node?', the answer would have been 'Yes, here is the URL to the API.' I am quite familiar with how SO works. Thank you for the mtools link, I didn't know about that and will go take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bit of digging into the mtools source code that @BlakesSeven provided (thanks!), I have discovered that through most MongoDB drivers it is possible to run database commands. For example, in C#, one could do:

```
MongoDB.Driver.IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("MyDatabase");
var result = database.RunCommandAsync<T>(
                         string.Format("{{ replSetInitiate : {0} }}", myReplSetConfig))
                     .Result;
```

or in Node:

```
db.runCommmand("{ replSetInitiate : " + myReplSetConfig + " }", function(err, callback){
    // Do stuff...
});
```

Various admin commands can be found in the MongoDB documentation. This is a good starting point: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/.

This stuff is very useful. I wish MongoDB promoted it more (if they do, I completely missed it)!

Comment: For the record [mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) was created by a MongoDB employee originally for their own personal use in the sort of analysis and testing tasks they regularly had to do and were therefore tired of all the "boilerplate" work that had to be done. The other thing is that "under the hood" then **everything** performed with client interactions to the database essentially boils down to issuing a "command statement". of which "most" are [listed here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/). Digging in drivers will show you even more still.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven. mtools actually looks like something that may suit my purpose. Going to give it a whirl and see how things go.